# How to deploy and maintain multiple chatbots agents

Tags: deployment, localization, dialogflow-es, chatbot

This post follow [this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/5W089oDBsC8) where I explain one of my problems. Currently, I have to found a way to publish and maintain a high number of agents. I am not limited to Dialogflow.

I need some integrations like the google assistant (text and vocal), facebook messenger, telegram and if possible others like Slack, Twitter, Twillio, Alexa...

Okay, so I have already produced some agents with Dialogflow to understand the technology. I also read some pages of the actions-on-google documentation and I did'nt found anything on this subject. So basically I have to implement this:

1. Deploy around X agents through differents integrations instanciations. I mean I really need X facebook contacts, X google assistant apps, etc.
2. Maintain one code-base but have the ability to add localized-features like the name of the chatbot, currency or just block some intents (for Dialogflow example but in a more generic way, dialogs triggers).

It is just possible ? I am thinking about a web UI that can handle some facilities like the deployment, the monitoring and the maintenance. I am wondering if it's not overkill and if a more easier solution than mine exists already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently possible to create agents automatically, although Dialogflow's V2 API provides a mechanism to update agents via JSON once they have been created; see the [restore](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/restore) and [import](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/import) endpoints.

Comment: Yep, it's my personnal conclusion on this subject to.